# Android WebView html file browse buttons are not selecting files. The ActivityResult.getResultCode() is always 0

Tags: java, android, webview, filebrowse

I have just started using Android, but I have used the Java language in the past.

I have loaded a web application in an android WebWiew. The app was published successfully but the file browse buttons did not work. I have tried searching for many days, but most of the code that I tried, either did not work or is outdated.

Related, answers on the internet too, are for old Android versions or were answered many years ago. For example, startActivityForResult() is now deprecated.

**The file selection dialog does open**, but after selecting the file nothing happens.
**The ActivityResult.getResultCode() is always returned as 0) zero**.

This is the string version of the result:

*ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}*

For now, I Just want the browse button file selections to work, so that these get uploaded with the form.

I have tried changing the permissions, and almost everything that I could.

Target SDK version is 33
Min SDK version is 25

I am posting the code that I have tried. For testing, I have replaced the app with a simple html page. I have tried accept='image/*' , attributes as well. Please let me know what I am missing?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private WebView webView;
        private static final int FILE_CHOOSER_ACTIVITY_CODE = 1;
        private ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath;
        private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
            String webUrl = getString(R.string.hosting_url);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
    
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    
            webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
            //webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            //webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    
            activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                            if (filePath != null) {
                                filePath.onReceiveValue(null);
                            }
                            System.out.println(result);
                            Log.d("info", "Result code is " + result.getResultCode());
                            if (result.getResultCode() == FILE_CHOOSER_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
                                Uri[] results = null;
    
                                Log.d("Info", "Result code  " + result.getResultCode());
                                //if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                Intent data = result.getData();
                                //Uri uri = new Uri(data.getData());
                                if (data != null) {
                                    if (null == filePath) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    results = new Uri[]{data.getData()};
                                    filePath.onReceiveValue(results);
                                    System.out.println(results.toString());
                                }
                                //} else {
                                //    filePath = null;
                                //}
                            }
    
                        }
                    }
    
            );
    
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                    filePath = filePathCallback;
                    if (checkPermissions()) {
                        Intent getContent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        //getContent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        getContent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        getContent.setType("*/*");
                        //String[] mimeTypes = {"text/*", "image/"};
                        //getContent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                        //getContent.createChooser(getContent, "Choose a File");
    
                        activityResultLauncher.launch(getContent);
    
                        return true;
    
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
    
                    return false;
                }
    
            });
    
    
        }
    
        public boolean checkPermissions() {
    
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    //|| ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                String requiredPermissions[] = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, requiredPermissions, 1);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
         ....
         ....
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> -->
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.abc"
            tools:targetApi="31"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    
    
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

test.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Upload
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
    <input type="file"/>
            <input type='submit' value='Upload Now' />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319946/uploading-files-through-the-camera-is-0-bytes-but-if-its-via-the-gallery-its-o

Comment: Thank you @blackapps. That question has helped. Thankfully, that question was posted today :-) I will work on it and post the result, or ask a question, if I face some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. The link provided by @blackapps has helped. This also allows file downloads, which I later realized did not work. This is partial code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath;
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String webUrl = getString(R.string.hosting_url);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Uri[] uris;


                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            if (data != null) {
                                if (data.getClipData() != null) { // more than one file

                                    int totalFiles = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                                    uris = new Uri[totalFiles];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                                        Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                        uris[i] = uri;
                                    }
                                } else { // one file
                                    uris = new Uri[]{data.getData()};
                                }
                                filePath.onReceiveValue(uris);

                            }

                        } else {
                            filePath.onReceiveValue(null);
                        }
                    }
                }

        );

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                filePath = filePathCallback;

                if (checkPermissions()) {
                    Intent getContent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    getContent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    getContent.setType("*/*");
                    if (fileChooserParams.getMode() == FileChooserParams.MODE_OPEN_MULTIPLE) {
                        getContent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    }
                    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, getContent);
                    activityResultLauncher.launch(chooserIntent);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        // .....
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        ) {
            String[] requiredPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, requiredPermissions, MainActivity.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MainActivity.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please click the browse button again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission is required to upload files, otherwise browse button will not work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "If permission was denied more than once, then from Settings, allow Media and file access permission for " + R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }


    }
}
```

AndoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

<!-- .... -->

</manifest>
```