# Uploading files through the camera is 0 bytes but if it's via the gallery it's ok

Tags: android, webview

I have an android webview application, when I upload a file through the gallery it's ok but when I go through the camera the file results are 0 bytes, I have code like this. Please help me

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            f_string = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = null;
            takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = create_image();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath",cam_path);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e ("TAG", "Image file cration failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    cam_path = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            myARL.launch(chooserIntent);
            return true;
        }




    });
```

Comment: You cannot use Uri.fromFile(). Use FileProvider and getUriForFile().